# insert query is not working in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

this is action url: `http://localhost/carsdirectory/users/dashboard`.

dashboad.ctp (i have select filed and in this select field i m fetching data from that filed car_type and table name car_types)

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'dashboard')); ?>

     <label class="ls-details-label">Type</label>
    <div class="ls-details-box">
        <?php 
            foreach ($car_types as $car_type)
            {
                $car_type_new[$car_type['Car_type']['id']]=
                                        $car_type['Car_type']['car_type'];
            }
            echo $this->Form->input('car_type',
                                    array(  'label'=>false,
                                            'options'=>$car_type_new,
                                            'empty'=>' Select ',
                                            'class'=>'styledselect_form_1'));
        ?>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Submit', 
                                    'name' => 'Submit',     
                                    'div' => array('class' => 'ls-submit')));?>
```

users_controller.php (controller)

```
class UsersController extends AppController{

   var $name = "Users";

   public function dashboard(){

      $this->loadModel('Car_type'); // your Model name => Car_type      
      $this->set('car_types', $this->Car_type->find('all'));

         if(!empty($this->data))
       {

        $this->loadModel('Car');

        if($this->Car->save($this->data))
        {
          $this->Session->setFlash('Detail has Been Saved');

          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'dashboard'));

        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Detail could not save'); 

        }

    }

}
```

car.php (model)

```
<?php
class Car extends appModel{
  var $name = "Car";
}
?>
```

i want to inset data car_type_id field in (table name cars) , but i m not able to do it

so plz help me

thanks in advance, vikas tyagi

Comment: What is the error is it going to the `else` ?

Comment: thanks for reply, i have done public but still going null value in car_type_id filed

Comment: Mr Naveen i m not getting any error but going null value in car_type_id filed

Comment: Your form returns `data[User][car_type]` and you're trying save in Car model.

Comment: Mr Paulo, wht should i do , could you explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Car.car_type_id', array(...));
```